# Watir Net::ReadTimeout (Net::ReadTimeout) => erreur javascript?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, watir

I have an `Net::ReadTimeout (Net::ReadTimeout)` error, but when I set `Watir.logger.level = :debug` I discover another error, maybe the one cause the second?

LOG :

```
1587345403921   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "/usr/bin/firefox" "-marionette" "--headless" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "/tmp/rust_mozprofileBh6eE6"
*** You are running in headless mode.
1587345404347   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid extension permission: mozillaAddons
1587345404347   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid extension permission: telemetry
1587345404347   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid extension permission: resource://pdf.js/
1587345404347   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid extension permission: about:reader*
JavaScript error: undefined, line 14: Error: An unexpected error occurred
JavaScript error: moz-extension://6bdb89cc-fe59-4593-9c54-e21de786aa9d/lib/picture_in_picture_overrides.js, line 15: Error: Incorrect argument types for pictureInPictureParent.setOverrides.
JavaScript error: resource:///modules/sessionstore/SessionStore.jsm, line 1325: uncaught exception: 2147746065
1587345405996   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 34985
```

There is many line with "JavaScript error". When I try same code (not headless) on local, there is no error at all...

How debug this javascript error?

I juste do on rails 6 (ruby 2.6.0) project with gem :

```
gem 'headless'
gem 'watir'
gem 'webdrivers'
gem 'watir-screenshot-stitch'
gem 'watir-scroll'
gem 'webdriver-user-agent'
```

simple code used :

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, profile: profile, headless: Rails.env.production?
browser.goto('www.google.fr')
```

With :

```
firefox -v
Mozilla Firefox 68.7.0esr
```

Comment: First. Headless gem and headless settings on Firefox are two different approaches to running headless. If you are on Linux, just go ahead and use the headless gem and don't worry about passing anything in to the browser instance. Second, what are you trying to do with profile? Most of what you want to do will be in capabilities, not in profile. What version of firefox are you using? Does your code work with Chrome?

Comment: I override prifile with : `profile['general.useragent.override']`. I don't have chrome driver to test (but it works on my local dev app), I want use FF ;) if I don't do `headless: true` (on local) the webbrowser start as normal (on prod. no because I have a debian with no interface), so just put gem headless in gemfile is not sufficient to start realy headless. `firefox -v
Mozilla Firefox 68.7.0esr
`

Comment: he's asking if it works on chrome more as information in the troubleshooting process than anything else.  None of the watir folks are the type to say 'just use another browser' as a fix unless you run into a bug in the browser itself that is beyond our ability to fix.  Watir was born as a test tool created by testers, we understand that testing using more than one type of browser is required, and that not being able to test a given commonly used browser is a bad thing.

Comment: If this is working with the exact same code on your local system, but not on the test system (prod? eek!) you might want to do 'Gem List' on both systems and confirm the versions of the gems you're using..  (it's not uncommon for our workstations to have more current gem versions than prod systems/vms/containers)

Comment: I don't use watir to test but to create bot, do you have better solution for do this? :)